# Accessing second array in a JSON decode using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I need to access the second array from a `JSON decoded` string, but I am having no luck.

The entire JSON string is displayed in `var RAW00`, and then split into `var RAW01` & `var RAW02`.
All 3 of these are for testing - `RAW00 is identical to msg`

When they are split - I can access either, depending on what variable I start of with, but when I use `RAW00` I cannot access the tutor section.

I will provide more detail if required, but my question is:

**How do I see and access the tutor array in the second `$.each` (nested) block??**]

Thanks :-)

```
success: function(msg)
{
    var test = "";
    var raw00 = {
        "allData": [
            {
                "class2": [
                    {
                        "tid": "1",
                        "name": "Monday 2"
                    },
                    {
                        "tid": "1",
                        "name": "Monday Test"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "tutor": [
                    {
                        "fname": "Jeffrey",
                        "lname": "Kranenburg"
                    },
                    {
                        "fname": "Jeffrey",
                        "lname": "Kranenburg"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    };

    var raw01 = {
        "allData": [
            {
                "class2": [
                    {
                        "tid": "1",
                        "name": "Monday 2"
                    },
                    {
                        "tid": "1",
                        "name": "Monday Test"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    };
    var raw02 = {
        "allData": [
            {
                "tutor": [
                    {
                        "fname": "Jeffrey",
                        "lname": "Kranenburg"
                    },
                    {
                        "fname": "Jeffrey",
                        "lname": "Kranenburg"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    };

    $.each(raw00.allData, function(index, entry) 
           {  
               $.each(entry.class2, function (index, data) 
                      {
                          console.log(this.name);
                          test += '<tr><td>'+this.name+'</td>';
                      });

               $.each(entry.tutor, function (index, data) 
                      {
                          console.log(this.fname);
                          test += '<td>'+this.name+'</td></tr>';
                      });

               $('#all-courses-table-content').html( test );
           });
```

Comment: `raw00` is not JSON, is not a string and not decoded anywhere?

Comment: It is JSON - validated it at jsonlint.com - It is a return of a PHP function, which encodes it.

Comment: [No, it's not](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2904131/1048572). JSON is always text. You've assigned a data structure to `raw00` (which is represented by the JSON-like object literal syntax in your program code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check whether the current element of the array is an object with `class2` property or `tutor` property.

```
$.each(raw00.allData, function(index, entry) {  
    if (entry.hasOwnProperty('class2')) {
        $.each(entry.class2, function (index, data) 
               {
                   console.log(this.name);
                   test += '<tr><td>'+this.name+'</td>';
               });
    }

    if (entry.hasOwnProperty('tutor')) {
        $.each(entry.tutor, function (index, data) 
               {
                   console.log(this.fname);
                   test += '<td>'+this.fname+'</td></tr>';
               });
    }

    $('#all-courses-table-content').html( test );
});
```

Things would probably be simpler if you redesigned the data structure. It generally doesn't make sense to have an array of objects when each object just has a single key and it's different for each. I suggest you replace the `allData` array with a single object, like this:

```
var raw00 = {
    "allData": {
        "class2": [
            {
                "tid": "1",
                "name": "Monday 2"
            },
            {
                "tid": "1",
                "name": "Monday Test"
            }
        ],
        "tutor": [
            {
                "fname": "Jeffrey",
                "lname": "Kranenburg"
            },
            {
                "fname": "Jeffrey",
                "lname": "Kranenburg"
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and +1 for the suggestion - will look into that